# JavaFX, how to work with multiple tableviews and their item selection

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am working with JavaFx and trying to solve the following problem:

I got  2 TableViews(A and B)(each with just one column). If I select one tableview item there should be information listet somewhere else, about the selected object.

When I select tableview A and click on an item, the information is shown and the item selected. thats fine.
Now when I try to select a tableview B item the information is not shown. It only works when I first click on the tableview A area (not clicking on direct item of A) and then clicking on the tableview B item.  What could be the reason for that?

I tried with     `tableview.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()` 
and adding mouseclick listener to deselect the other tableview. didnt work.

Maybe there is a easy way to say "forget all selections before"? thank you!

Following Code shows Information when clicks happen:

```
.... 
initTableConfiguration();
categoryTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
         (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->  showBoardObjectDetails(newValue));  
noteTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
         (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->  showBoardObjectDetails(newValue));}


private void initTableConfiguration() {     
    categoryColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            cellData -> cellData.getValue().titleProperty());
    noteColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            cellData -> cellData.getValue().titleProperty());
}
```

And a listener for the clicks:

```
categoryTableView.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me){          
            noteTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();     

        }
    });
noteTableView.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me){
            categoryTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

        }
    });
```

Displays the Information:

```
public void showBoardObjectDetails(Object object){
    if(object != null){
        Category category;
        Note note;
        if(object.getClass()==Category.class){
            category = (Category) object;
            titleLabel.setText(category.getTitle());                
            dateLabel.setVisible(false);    
            staticDateLabel.setVisible(false);
            contentTextArea.setVisible(false);
            staticContentLabel.setVisible(false);
        }else if(object.getClass()==Note.class){
            note = (Note) object;
            staticContentLabel.setVisible(true);
            staticDateLabel.setVisible(true);
            dateLabel.setVisible(true);
            contentTextArea.setVisible(true);
            titleLabel.setText(note.getTitle());            
            dateLabel.setText(note.getDate().toString());           
            contentTextArea.setText(note.getText());
        }
    }else{
        titleLabel.setText("");
        dateLabel.setText("");
        contentTextArea.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's pretty much impossible to know what might be going wrong without seeing the code that causes it.

Comment: @James_D okay, now it should be enough context

Comment: They are tableviews and not listviews right? Correct your question.

Comment: @UlukBiy thats correct, thanks and sorry for that.

Comment: _now it should be enough context_ No, it isn't - please read the page that @James_D referenced and comply with it. <rant> I really really really don't get why you don't make it EASY for us to be helpful, at least not after you have been guided at what is required from you. After all, it's YOUR problem and you ask for OUR help for FREE. <rant/>

Comment: @kleopatra calmn down! do something else, if you dont want to help. i mentioned the relevant code now. When you think there is not enough information, then just tell me what to add, but stop complaining about new people on stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you read the link and do what it says there? You should create, from scratch, a ***new application*** that has *only* the items relevant to the problem you are trying to solve: i.e. in this case two tables and something (e.g. a label) to update on selection. The point is that if you create a complete example, you are guaranteed to include the code that is in error. If you just include code snippets you are likely to omit the real cause of the problem, or omit some details of what you actually want to happen, or both.

Comment: carefully compare what you provided with the requirement described in the reference - if you think they are the same, you probably should do something other than programming (no offense intended, I mean it literally). And no, I'm not going away, just because there's yet another newbie who seems to think s/he can freely take our time. It's IMPOSSIBLE to help if you don't do your part in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the problem is when you click on the 2nd tableview, you are calling `clearSelection()` on the 1st. So this `clearSelection()` is triggering  `selectedItemProperty()` changed event on the 1st tableview again.

Instead of adding mouse pressed event handlers to tableviews, try this

```
categoryTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
         (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->  {
                   noteTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                   showBoardObjectDetails(newValue);
     } );

noteTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
         (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->  {
                   categoryTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                   showBoardObjectDetails(newValue);
     } );
```

Then remove mouse handlers.

Comment: thank you.
now it's better than before but not working like i want it to.
is create item on A, on B and the information is shown correctly, when I click first on A item then on B item. 

But when I click von B to A item, just B item informatin is shown (so no update). That only works, when creating another A item clicking on this new item and then the old item. now the values are shown correctly. strange behavior.

Comment: @qecce - most probably there's nothing strange per se,  just something wrong with the code you are not showing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

now it worked with the following:

```
categoryTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
         (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {                       
             if(newValue !=null){
                 noteTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                 showBoardObjectDetails(newValue);
             }                           
         });  

    noteTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
         (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {                       
             if(newValue !=null){
                 categoryTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                 showBoardObjectDetails(newValue);                   
             }              
         });
```

Thats nearly what Uluk Biy posted. Thanks!